# Downloading file from MySQL database in php produces empty file

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, when downloading the file uploaded in MySQL table in LONGBLOB field, it produces an empty file. In specific case, the downloaded file (a PDF) has the correct size, correct title, correct number of pages and dimensions, but the pages are completely blank.

here is the code I'm using:

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
mysql_select_db($database_dbconn, $dbconn);
$query   = "SELECT cvform_file_name, cvform_file_type, cvform_file_size, cvform_att_file   FROM t_cvform WHERE idCvform = $id";
$result  = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($cvform_file_name, $cvform_file_type, $cvform_file_size, $cvform_att_file) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$cvform_file_name);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-length: ".$cvform_file_size);
header("Content-type: ".$cvform_file_type);
print $cvform_att_file;
}
```

Any idea? Thanke

Comment: Have you verified that `$cvform_att_file` actually has content?

Comment: Yes, it has contents, the LONGBLOB field in database shows binary data, size is corresponding to original file uploaded.